# Markdown method in React. Not getting a return value that is in html

Tags: reactjs, markdown

I would like to create a method in React using markdown, simply to receive a string like "Hello *World*!" and render it in html.  At the moment my program is returning the string "Hello *World*!" without rendering it in html.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";

       class App extends React.Component 
       {
         constructor(props){
         super(props)
         this.changeToMarkdown = this.changeToMarkdown.bind(this)
       }



        changeToMarkdown(str)
        {
        var markdown = require( "markdown" ).markdown;
         return markdown.toHTML(str);
        }


       render()
       {

          return (
             <div>
                <p>{this.changeToMarkdown("Hello *World*!")}</p>
             </div>
            )
        } 
    }    

    export default App
```

Answer (score 2):

You're already importing `react-markdown`; why not use it?

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactMarkdown>{"Hello *World*!"}</ReactMarkdown>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here's a simple CodePen that shows this in action](https://codepen.io/tupton/pen/XWXjvar).

Comment: Can I incorporate React Markdown components into another component?  I think the answer is yes.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but a react markdown component is just like any other component and it can indeed be composed with or into other components.